# Sending MySQL Queries in bulk to save memory

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm currently trying to insert multiple rows per second into my SQL database. While doing this im coming across that the program is consuming upwards of 1GB ram steadily increasing. The program then crashes due to running out of memory.

I have tried sending the queries in bulk by stringing them together and then running. My current solution does work, however, I'm 90% sure it is the cause of the memory consumption

```js
function insertUsername(id, username, discrim, unix) {
    vars = [id, username, discrim, unix];
    conn.query("SELECT username, discrim FROM usernames WHERE discordID = ? LIMIT 1", id, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!results[0] == null) {
            if (results[0].username != username || results[0].discrim != discrim) {
                conn.query(insertUsernameSQL, vars, function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            }

        }
        return;
    });
    conn.query(insertUsernameSQL, vars, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}
```

```js
function insertMessage(unix, id, username, discrim, message, server, sid) {

    vars = [unix, id, username, discrim, message, sid, server];
    conn.query(insertMessageSQL, vars, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

}
```

My attempt at a bulk sender:

```js
function transaction_bldr(vars){
  sql_transaction.push(vars);
  console.log(sql_transaction.length);
  if (sql_transaction.length > 1){
    conn.query(sql, [sql_transaction], function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(1);
    });
      sql_transaction = [];
  }
}
```

After using the first two functions I get this: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/619654531596288000/619963742339203122/unknown.png

Comment: I don't think your code is the cause of the memory-leak. Have you used a profiler or debugger to take a look at the process' heap usage?

Comment: No, not yet, Honestly I don't know how to do that. Could you give some advice? Thanks

Comment: Progress, I have checked it out. It seems that there a bunch of internal arrays taking up a lot of memory. I can't really do anything about those, so what should I do

Comment: Post to pastebin.com and share the links of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; with UPTIME of at least 4 hours of productive use. B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C) RAM available D) CORES E) storage is ROTATING, SSD or NVME?

Comment: @WilsonHauck  Storage type is irrelevant to memory usage at this scale. I don't believe the OP is experiencing problems with excessive disk IO buffering (and they wouldn't manifest themselves as Node complaining about running out of memory).

Comment: I seemed to fix it by reducing the cache size on the library